# HTML Displaying table data with specific value only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table and I want only those rows to be displayed which is having a specific value in table data corresponding to specific table head. You may assume just like a SQL query, for example

```
select * from mytable where name="jone";
```

Code:

```js
$("#datatable").find("td").each(function() {
  var test = $(this).text();
  alert(test);
});
```

```html
  <div class="x_content">
                    <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Position</th>
                          <th>Office</th>
                          <th>Age</th>
                          <th>Start date</th>
                          <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                          <td>System Architect</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh</td>
                          <td>61</td>
                          <td>2011/04/25</td>
                          <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                          <td>Accountant</td>
                          <td>Tokyo</td>
                          <td>63</td>
                          <td>2011/07/25</td>
                          <td>$170,750</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use [**`:contains`**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to select elements having specified content

```js
$("#datatable tbody tr").hide();
$("#datatable tr:contains('Edinburgh')").show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="x_content">
  <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```